# How do you display all values in an object?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

This is a Mongoid object, but I think it applies for all objects.  How do I split up @product into key, value pairs when @product looks like this:

```
#<Product _id: 4e7cd178e66de72d70000010, _type: nil, 
created_at: 2011-09-23 18:35:36 UTC, 
updated_at: 2011-09-23 18:35:36 UTC, brand: "crystalrock", 
name: "Crazy Fool Specialty Tank", retailer: nil, model: nil, 
sku: nil store: {"id"=>"36033", "name"=>"Ed Hardy"}, 
product_id: "684", sku_number: "D9WAFDCR", category_primary: "Tanks">
```

I would think it would be a object method, but I don't see one that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like @product.attributes is a Mongoid method that works.